# Exporting Large (30 million row) Attribute Tables

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, export, venus

I'm attempting to export an attribute table that contains 30 million rows (with 10 columns) to a .txt file. I've been able to export smaller portions of it (e.g. selecting and exporting the first 100 records), but the sheer number of rows slows the export process to a crawl or just crashes it.

Clarification: I have a raster that covers about 90% of Venus with ~4 km resolution, and I need to extract the latitude, longitude, and pixel value for each pixel. I thought the best way would be to use **Raster to Point**, then **Add XY Coordinates**, and export the table of the resulting shapefile. If there's a better way, I'd love to learn!

Using the ArcPy script described in the answers worked on a similar, but smaller shapefile (~10% of Venus, same resolution), but when run on the larger shapefile of 90% of Venus, the IDLE shell quit without warning after an hour of running. Any ideas of what caused/could prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest pure python in combination with the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`. A basic export to text file code sample looks like this:

```
out_file = r'C:\path_to_data\output.txt'
input_feature_class = r'C:\path_to_data\your_input_data.shp'
with open(out_file, 'w') as w_file:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class, '*') as s_cur:
        w_file.write(','.join(s_cur.fields) + '\n')
        for row in s_cur:
            output_data = ','.join(map(str, row))
            w_file.write(output_data +'\n')
```

This is a simplified version of the code, that simply converts the field values to a single string separated by comma and writes it to file. Without knowing more about your data it is difficult to provide custom formatting, such as handling the `SHAPE` field and other aspects of the export/file writing. The documentation for [`arcpy.da.SearchCursor` is here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm). The above code snippet should get you on your way.

If you can provide more specifics about your data I can certainly clarify and give tips to handle certain types of fields.

Comment: You can access the fields returned by the cursor as `s_cur.fields`.

Comment: @Paul good point as well. Given that this code is already going to create and use a cursor, why waste time with `arcpy.ListFields`. I have updated the answer to utilize the `.fields`. Props to you, I did not know cursors had field names as an attribute.

Comment: Better to ***always*** use `arcpy.ListFields`, since a `*` query is going to return meta columns like the length and area, and rowid.  You also want to be careful if/how you query the geometry column, so that it comes back in WKT. And if you do return geometry, you certainly *don't* want to make the output comma-delimited -- tab or pipe are the only ways to fly.

Comment: For the smaller attribute table (1.42 million), it exported the first 1.33 million before quitting without warning, and for the larger attribute table (30 million), it exported the first 1.39 million before again quitting IDLE without warning. I saw that it had exported nearly 1.4 million the first time and didn't check until now to realize it didn't completely export the full amount.